# selector for occurances of elements but aren't children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to somehow add an inline style for each element that is beyond a certain threshold. To explain this in a code format my sample is this:

```
var listItems = $(".subitem");
    listItems.each(function(index, value) {
        console.log(listItems.length);
        if (listItems.length > 5) {
            // for every ".subitem" that is the 6th, 7th or however many but
            // beyond the fifth, inject an inline style
        }
 }
```

My first thought was `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` but are both out as the markup loosely follows like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="subitem"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subitem"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subitem"></div>
</div>
```

With this markup structure (that cannot be changed) how best can I iterate through each instance of `.subitem` and add an inline style to the occurrences that are beyond a limit?

Comment: `console.log(listItems.length);`? Shouldn't you track `index` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close.  As you see, the index is passed in when you loop through your list items.  If you see an index beyond 4 (that is, after the 5th element), then you can use jquery to apply the styling you desire.

```
var listItems = $(".subitem");
    listItems.each(function(index, value) {
        if (index > 4) {
            // apply styling specific to elements 6 and beyond
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can filter using [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector or [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to exclude indexes below the value set.

```
listItems.filter(':gt(4)').each(function(){
   $(this).doSomething()       
})
// or
$(".subitem:gt(4)").each(function(){...
// or using slice()
listItems.slice(4).each(function(){
```

Comment: Just added another one `slice()`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if length is more than 6 instead of checking if the element itself is beyond the 6th.

Since the parameter 'index' is the position of the element you are iterating in this mooment you should use it:

```
   var listItems = $(".subitem");
listItems.each(function(index, value) {
    if (index > 5) {
        $(this).css("color","red");
    }
 });
```